# My character keeps falling through a barrier in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I made a test sprite with this script but my character falls through the ground when I jump fast or at random but stays on while he is moving slow but falls through when jumping/landing fast.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class code : MonoBehaviour { 
//void FixedUpdate() {
        /*if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
         {
            int Left = 1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
        {
            int Right = 1;
        }


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {

        }
        */

public float speed1 = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F; 
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

void FixedUpdate() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    // is the controller on the ground?
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        //Feed moveDirection with input.
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0,        Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        //Multiply it by speed.
        moveDirection *= speed1;
        //Jumping
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    //Applying gravity to the controller
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    //Making the character move
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}   
}
```

Comment: did you attached collider to your ground and your character ?

Comment: You didn't post the code for `CharacterController`. This is an issue because it looks like `isGrounded` isn't being flagged properly.

Comment: @halfer I think he meant while.

Comment: Thanks @Alox, seems like it!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem of every physics engine.

physics calculation is a costly operation thus cannot be run every frame. To reduce overheat (at the cost of reducing accuracy) Unity only updates physics every 0.02 seconds (that number is configurable).

You could reduce that number but the smaller it is the more overheat the physics engine does and it still cannot guarantee 100% accuracy. To achieve 100% accuracy you should not rely on the physics engine but do it yourself instead.

Below is the code to check for collision of a bullet that flies in a straightline (taken from one of my pet projects).

```
IEnumerator Translate()
{
    var projectile = Projectile.transform; // Cache the transform
    while (IsMoving)
    {
        // Calculate the next position the transform should be in the next frame.
        var delta = projectile.forward * ProjectileSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        var nextPosition = projectile.position + delta;
        // Do a raycast from current position to the calculated position to determine if a hit occurs
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Linecast(projectile.position, nextPosition, out hitInfo, CollisionLayerMask))
        {
            projectile.position = hitInfo.point;
            OnCollision(hitInfo); // Ok, we hit
        }
        else projectile.position = nextPosition; // Nope, haven't hit yet
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

In your case, you only need to do raycast when your character starts to jump to determine if he hits the ground, if he does, you do something to prevent him from falling through.

Comment: if u don't mind can u tell me the code to stop him from falling through thanks(I'm kina a nub :/) Thank you!

Comment: Did you attach a `rigidbody` to your character (together with `CharacterController`)? If that was the case, you could remove it since `CharacterController` can work alone from Unity 4 without `rigidbody`. If for some reason, you couldn't remove it, turn on `isKinematic` or at least turn off 'useGravity'. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html